# How to Show specific section of a url in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

I want to show specific div of a webpage in iframe instead of full page.

https://www.eventcombo.com/e/in-groups-rang-barse-2017---holi-cruise-around-new-york-27179

I want to use only #ticketSection from this url.
http://prntscr.com/emypd1

Comment: you can download the page to a string, parse the html, removing everything except the div you want to keep and then set the html of the iframe to that

Comment: use jquery `$('selector').load("https://www.eventcombo.com/e/in-groups-rang-barse-2017---holi-cruise-around-new-york-27179 #ticketSection")`